# Missing $ inserted - referring to bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, biber

I'm getting

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ ...y[prenote=myprenote,title={Bibliography}]
```

The respective line is

```
\printbibliography[prenote=myprenote,title={Bibliography}]
```

Is there something off in that line or must the fault lie with the bibliography itself?

The bib contains underscores in URLs, which according to some search results here may cause problems. But does that also count for bibliographies?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use `\usepackage{url}`. Just a guess in the absence of MWE.

Comment: url package is used, so I'll create a mwe. Will add it soon.

Comment: For future readers: a solution I found helpful is entering scrollmode ('salvage' mode) by hitting s when LaTeX encounters the error, allowing the pdf to be created, then scanning the bibliography for math mode text (italics in weird spaces). Typically this will be a URL in the wrong field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it was rather simple. The title of a publication contained the $ sign. Found this when trying to create a mwe. Escaping it like this helped:

```
Title = {Gartner Says Worldwide Enterprise IT Spending to Reach \$2.7 Trillion in 2012},
```

It's somewhat embarassing that I didn't try figuring it out like that myself. Thanks for the kick in the butt and maybe this question will at least help someone else later.

Comment: Self-learning is sometimes the best method ;-)

Comment: This is indeed a hell-like problem with bibliography. I never imagined until I saw your post that the problem is in fact there within `.bib` source. Thanks!